# Rails 4 custom named route not calling correct property of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

As per http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters I am defining a route with a custom named route parameter instead of `:id` to create friendly URLs. routes.rb looks like:

```
resources :spaces, param: :name
```

Running `rake routes` does indeed give the correct paths with dynamic segments:

```
space GET    /spaces/:name(.:format)                spaces#show
```

But using `space_path` still tries to retrieve the ID:

```
irb(main):009:0> app.space_path space
=> "/spaces/1"
```

were it should give "/spaces/foo" (assuming that the Space with `id=1` has `name=foo`)

I can explicitly do:

```
irb(main):009:0> app.space_path space.name
=> "/spaces/foo"
```

But then I lose the whole point of the dynamic paths, and all of my views become far more brittle. Should the dynamic paths not recognize the property to retrieve?

I do know that I can override `to_params` in the model, but again, isn't that making the model brittle? Shouldn't the dynamic path recognize the name of the dynamic segment and retrieve the correct property off of the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app.space_path` is going to take the first argument you give it and put it in place of `:name`. If the argument is an ActiveModel instance, it will call `to_param` on it, which, unless you override it, will return the value of the `id` attribute—in this case `1`, not `foo`.

If you want `app.space_path(space)` to return `/spaces/foo` you'll need to override `Space#to_param`:

```
class Space < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def to_param
    name
  end
end
```

The only thing `:name` in your route does is determine what the key for that value in `params` is in your controller, i.e. if `/spaces/foo` is requested, `params[:name]` will be `"foo"`.

Comment: So `:name` in the route only determines what gets put in the params, i.e. URL->params, and not URL construction? So if I have `/spaces/:foo/:bar/:zed`, it will not automatically pull the properties `foo` `bar` and `zed` from my `Space` model? I would need to explicitly do `path(space.foo, space.bar, space.zed)`?

Comment: That's correct. You could do `path(*space.values_at(:foo, :bar, :zed))`, but you don't really gain anything that way.

Comment: It is a pity. It would be really impressive if it could cut both ways. Thanks for the help.